# Onde posso achar os métodos do Python?

Tags: python

Olá, eu gostaria de ver como são escritos os métodos que já vem por padrão no python, como por exemplo o str.split(). Ja procurei na pasta em que o python foi instalado mas não encontrei. Gostaria de saber se tem como ver.

Comment: Acho, que é isso que você deseja: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332743/source-code-for-str-split)

Comment: Baixe o codigo fonte do python [aqui](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/)

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja apenas ver os métodos que você pode usar já embutidos no python, sem ver as implementações, você pode usar o

```py
 dir(__builtins__)
```

Com isso ele mostrará todos os métodos builtins disponível no python para você usar. Caso queira ter a cesso a documentação de determinado método basta usar a função help().

```py
help(str.split)
```

Dessa forma você obtém o docstring do método e pode saber como ele funciona.
Creio que seja a maneira ideal para se fazer consultas a certas funciolidades da linguagem, pois após estudar vai conhecer mais é mais os métodos e funções, é caso precise relembrar o nome de uma função, ou como ela funciona, use os dois métodos passados acima. Claro se você ainda está começando o ideal é um curso para que você tenha de fato um aprendizado concreto não só da linguagem, mais também de boas práticas na linguagem, técnicas e tudo mais.